# Why does the variable value get deleted when placed after DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get this path:

`C:\xampp\htdocs\site\folder\filename.jpg`

By doing:

```
$i = new Imagick('C:\xampp\htdocs\site\folder' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename);
```

This returns:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\folder\
```

But it doesn't have the `$filename`.

I have also tried:

```
$i = new Imagick(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'folder' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename);
```

This returns:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\files\folder\filename.jpg
```

So I tried adding `..\` to get away from the `files` folder:

```
$i = new Imagick(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..\folder' .  DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename);
```

But that returns:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\files\..\folder\filename.jpg
```

How can I get to the correct folder?

Comment: you can use `realpath()` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) to expand path and get rid of `..`'s.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that `$filename` doesn't exist/is blank in the first sample. Because that should work as is.

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = 'filename.jpg';
$i = new Imagick('C:\xampp\htdocs\site\folder' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename);
```

This should give the correct value